# PHP - Insert each line of textarea containing columns separated by comma on database

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, laravel

Im trying to insert multiple lines on db,these lines will by pasted from excel sheet,already concatened by comma

Example:

how to insert multiple lines?

View:

```
<form action="insert" method="post">
    @csrf
    <label for="values" class="control-label">Values:</label>

    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="data" id="data" rows="10" cols ="50">
            name,fullname,age
            name2,fullname,age
            name3,fullname,age
            name4,fullname,age
        </textarea>
    </div> 
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public function insert(Request $request) 
{
    $data= explode("\n",$request->data);
    $array = array_filter($data, 'trim')

    foreach($arry as $line){
        Tabletarget::insert($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this...

```
<form action="/insert" method="post">
       @csrf
         <label for="values" class="control-label">Values:</label>
           <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="data[]" value="name" />
                <input type="text" name="data[]" value="fullname" />
                <input type="text" name="data[]" value="age" />
                <button id="btn-save" name="btn-save" type="submit" name="submit" 
class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-save">
          </div> 
</form>

public function insert(Request $request) 
{
  $data= explode("\n",$request->data);
  $array = array_filter($data, 'trim')
  $datas = Input::get('data');
  foreach($datas as $data) {
    Tabletarget::insert($data);
  }
}
```

Check more details.. [Laravel Forms](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#forms)

enjoy coding~! :)

Comment: But this is 3 inputs separated, i need  to have insert each line of a textarea on db